# How does AWS Lightsail Container Service manage memory?

Tags: docker, python, amazon-lightsail

I have a container deployment running on Lightsail that manipulates and returns a list of [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) objects. I'm using these objects because Lightsail container deployments do not support persistent volumes.

When I try to return these objects, I get an empty response which isn't the case when the container is running locally. Hence, I suspect this issue has something to do with the way containers deployed on Lightsail works and how Lightsail implements Docker volumes.

I'd like to know if this issue arises from how Lightsail works and what other options I have with regards to deploying my image on AWS.

Thank you.

Comment: Would EFS solve your problem? It's a proper filesystem you can attach to many compute services in AWS including Lambda and containers... https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/efs-and-lightsail/

Comment: EFS connects to Lightsail Instances and not containers deployed on Lightsail. I think I may have to find another means of deploying my container without Lightsail